# Различное поведение в зависимости от applicationId

Tags: android

В моём проекте не работал `AlarmManager` (я вешал на него `BradcastReceiver`, который у меня не вызывался).

Создал новый проект с другим `applicationId`, написал в нём отдельно код, который через заданное время выводил оповещение (структура такая же: `AlarmManager`, `BroadcastReceiver`). В новом проекте всё заработало.

Проблема:

a) копирую работающий новый код в старый проект - он (код) перестаёт работать

b) копирую неработающий код старого проекта в новый - он (код) начинает работать

c) в работающем новом проекте меняю `applicationId` на любой другой - перестаёт работать

d) в неработающем старом проекте меняю `applicationId` на тот, что в новом, - начинает работать

Если в случаях a и b можно предположить, что я забывал указывать что-то в файлах `Manifest` или `gradle`, то в случаях c и d, насколько я понимаю, такие предположения звучат немного абсурдно.

Вопрос: как можно объяснить эту ситуацию - и как с ней бороться? (не критично, конечно, но хочется писать со старым `applicationId`, так как в гугле уже висит альфа-версия, и на данный проект с изменённым Id уже ничего не залить).

Стоит добавить, что в каждый момент тестирования, когда какой-либо проект устанавливался на устройство, все прошлые/прочие версии были удалены.

//Пункты a, b, c, d никак хронологически не связаны.

**UPD1:**

`Manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.packagename">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Receiver"></receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.packagename;

import ...;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

`Receiver.java`

```
package com.packagename;
import ...;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.d("abc", "here");
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packagename"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Покажитекакой нибудь код. Собственно ресивера, как аларм делаете, манифест и `build.gradle`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил :)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `action` для интента ресивера, прописав также `intent-filter` в манифесте в тег ресивера. Ну и ещё можно проверить что у вас совпадают `applicationId` и `package` атирибут в манифесте в момент смены первого.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил action, не работает. applicationId и package совпадают.

Нашёл некоторые материалы, судя по всему, эта проблема актуальна только для некоторых моделей **Huawei Honor** и **Asus Zenfone**. Я тестирую на Zenfone. _Как решить, не знаю_. Сегодня попробую на других.
[stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134518/what-causing-android-device-asus-zenfone-2-alarm-manager-not-working)
[stackoverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171730/alarmmanager-not-working-on-asus-zenfone-2-devices-with-android)
[4PDA](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=812614)

Comment: Попробуйте в манифесте указать ресиверу полное имя `<receiver android:name="com.packagename.Receiver"></receiver>`

Comment: @woesss Спасибо за ответ! Попробовал, поведение не поменялось (не работает). Насколько я понял, на указанных моделях смартфонов есть дополнительно написанный заводской код (у меня это _ASUS Mobile Manager_), который блокирует срабатывание `AlarmManager`, действие `BroadcastReceiver` и тому подобное. Это не Doze, а именно отдельное системное приложение. Если ручками в нём добавить разрешение на "автозапуск" своего приложения, всё начинает работать. Но я не знаю, как это _сделать в коде_. Кроме всего прочего, это не объясняет различное поведение при разных `applicationId` :D

Comment: Видимо это причуды этого самого чудо-манагера. Если его писали нормальные люди, то возможно он принимает некий интент, в ответ на который запрашивает у юзера добро на Ваше приложение. Ну как минимум Вы можете попросить юзера сделать это ручками и запустить ему окно с настройками

Comment: @woesss Да, это причуды "этого самого". Проблема в том, что я не могу найти как раз, что пихать в интент, чтобы обратиться к manager'у - или как определить, что он вообще стоит на устройстве (чтобы вывести пользователю запрос).
Не подскажете, где можно найти подобную информацию?